# CNAME problem with Bluehosting? With AWS Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, bluehost

I'm having a doubt with my actions right now.

I tried to create `load balancer` on AWS

and they gave some thing like

[image]

Now I'm using **BlueHost** for my DNS Provider

So I tried to put the `Name` (`_46cc9****.domain.com.`) value from AWS to Bluehost `Host` field

Also tried to put `Value` (`_8fd103b4*******.auiqqraehs.acm-validations.aws.`) field from aws to bluehost `Points To` field

but it only accepts if I disregard the `underscore`

[image]

Am I doing this right? Because seems something is wrong.

As you can see image above. It only gets the encrypted text for both `HOST` and `POINTS TO`

Comment: *"but it only accepts if..."*  What does "only accepts" mean?  Is there an error message?

Comment: That validation record screenshot from AWS does not appear to be related to the creation of a load balancer. It looks like you are trying to setup a domain name in Route53, which is not needed to simply create a load balancer. There's nothing in any of your screenshots or info that is in any way related to a load balancer.

Comment: Having a similar issue. Did you eventually solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. I was able to solve it please see my answer. @SFlagg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my Problem by doing the following

Based on my Exploring, I needed to contact the domain provider just to add the CNAME  that I need. So they put it for me.

After CNAME has been placed to my domain provider. My Load Balancer Certificate automatically gets Verified.

From that point you already have the Load Balancer with SSL attached itself.

That's why I was able to mapped my A Record for `www.domain.com` , `wildcard *.domain.com` and `domain.com` in the Route53 using my Load Balancer created.

From that point it's already pointed to your domain.

Hope this helps others.

**IN ADDITION**
If you're running

apache 2.4 on your Linux AMI 2.

You may want to configure here your VHOST Configuration & Redirect permant of Port 80 to 443. This will allow you to make the site automatically redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: Can confirm - BlueHost apparently does not allow DNS record values to start with an underscore (_) by default. I had to contact them and get them to add it manually. 

(One note: I think they changed a setting on my account, because ever since I contacted them, I've had no issues adding values with leading underscores.)